# iOS: How to convert \U to \u

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, utf-8

1. I have NSString which is unicode encoded. For example عنم١٢ which is internally represented like `"\U0639\U0646\U0645\U0661\U0662\U0663"`.
2. I am sending this string to a remote server which is basically a LAMP server. **Please note that I do not have any access to that server**.
3. The server seems to have problem with \U, but works fine for \u.
4. I tried the following piece of code which did not work for me:

   ```
   NSString *resourceparams = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sender,nil];
   NSLog(@"before replace resourceparams: %@", resourceparams);
   resourceparams = [resourceparams stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\U" withString:@"\\u"];
   NSLog(@"after replace resourceparams: %@", resourceparams);
   ```

Any suggestions ?

Edit: (Adding how this data is sent in the body of a Post request)

```
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];  
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];   
NSEnumerator * enumerator = [[paramDict allKeys] objectEnumerator];  
NSString * dataKey = nil;
while (( dataKey = [enumerator nextObject]) ) {  
    id dataVal = [paramDict objectForKey: dataKey];  
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundry] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if([dataVal isKindOfClass: [NSData class]]) {  
        NSString* contentDisposition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"file.ext\"\r\n", dataKey];  
        [postBody appendData: [contentDisposition dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
        [postBody appendData:dataVal];  
    } else {  
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", dataKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
        [postBody appendData:[dataVal dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
    }
```

Comment: What is output given by both NSLog statement?

Comment: output is same as shown in example: عنم١٢

Comment: remove the ",nil" from your first line of code and try

Comment: it should work for you . can you please show some more details of your code?

Comment: What do you mean with "I have a NSString which is UTF-8 encoded"? A NSString encapsulates *any* string. The original encoding is irrelevant, unless NSString cannot decode it during creation. The "encoding" is only relevant when you represent the string as a stream of code units. What are you sending, the *unicode encoded* string, e.g. "\U0639\U0646\U0645\U0661\U0662\U0663"?

Comment: can you show also your logs?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: OK. Fine let's say whatever the builtin encoding NSString is using is there. My core problem is that \U is creating problem but \u works fine.

Comment: What character encoding does the server expect?

Comment: @sbooth: Server works fine if \u (small case is used). What I mean and saw on web for encoding is "\u0639" is used in most cases instead of "\U0639" (for example).

Comment: Is that `\U` part of the *original* string? That is, the *original* string has been created by encoding the very first original string ("١٢") via an *Unicode escape scheme*? And should that string containing the "Unicode Escape Sequences" be transmitted to the server?

Comment: "\u" or "\U" is not a character encoding but a way of escaping characters.  An encoding is UTF-8, UTF-16, or the like.  Do you need a way to escape non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @sbooth: Yes, that's what my problem is, I already described in my problem that the internal representation uses \U for escape sequence instead of \u which I have seen mostly on web sites and discussion threads. So "\U0639" forms one character and I can not replace part of character to correct it.

Comment: @gmuhammad: "\U0639" is only used in the source code (and *sometimes* by NSLog) to represent the characters, because some editors have problems with non-ASCII characters. The "\U" is not part of the internal representation, and is not sent to the server (unless you use some special encoding like NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding :-)  Therefore *"The server seems to have problem with \U, but works fine for \u"* does not make much sense to me. What do you mean exactly with *"works fine for \u"*? - Perhaps you can provide more information: How do you sent the data, how is the data formatted ...

Comment: @gmuhammad: You have to find out in what encoding/format the server expects the characters, otherwise we can only make wild guesses. My wild guess: Perhaps you have to sent it as JSON?

Comment: @MartinR: I am putting this variable in NSDictionary, and when I used the po dict in debugger it shows me resourceparams = "\U0639\U0646\U0645\U0661\U0662\U0663", When I communicate to the server guy why my request is getting failed, he replied like that \U is creating problems. I don't know deep details about the server.

Comment: @gmuhammad: `po dict` in the debugger uses "\Unnnn" for all non-ASCII characters, that does not mean anything. - The important question is: How do you convert the NSDictionary to a string or data that is sent to the server?

Comment: I have shared some piece of code, for some reason I can not share all the code. I hope it'll be enough.

Comment: @gmuhammad If you have more code to add, then edit your question and add it there. You get all the space you need and it will be formatted correctly. In the comments it just looks like gibberish.

Comment: Done. edit the original question.

Comment: What is this supposed to do (besides produce a compiler warning: `NSString *resourceparams = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sender,nil];`  That's simply assigning sender to resourceparms in a rather expensive way, and the nil just produces the compiler warning.

Comment: (I suspect that your problem is that you're sending the data with the wrong encoding specified.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: I think it has nothing to do with NSString *resourceparams = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sender,nil]; because it's working on a different type of server i.e. Google App Engine.

Comment: Nevertheless, that statement is nonsense.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I agree to some extent that code is not up to standards,  but actual problem here is that code is working for App Engine and not for LAMP Server, and I am discussing it here because may be someone  already faced the same problem.

Comment: Do you understand why that statement is nonsense?  If not, then there's no use trying to fix the rest of your code.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I think what you are suggesting is to use sender variable  directly instead of creating another duplicate string. If this is what you mean then I have already tried that too and it has no effect.

Comment: No, what I'm suggesting is that you don't know what you're doing.  Have you fixed the nonsense statement yet?

Comment: @Hot Licks: I have removed the resourceparams variable and used the sender variable directly which is already a NSString*. But it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a lowercase stringobject. Where your function will look like:

```
NSString *resourceparams = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sender,nil] lowerCaseString];
```

This will non-capitalize each nsstring object.

Comment: I did not get your point \U is the escape sequence used for encoding. How it'll work?

Comment: What do you suppose that will do to ordinary upper-case Latin characters?